# getting NS record type using C# (dns)

Tags: c#, dns

Just wondering if there is any way to get the NS records in C#. I have read on the MSDN and there seems to be a DNS class that can return the host IP address. However, I am after the NS record type.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I recall, this functionality is not built in to C#.

However, there are some no-license and open-source-license components that will provide much richer DNS functionality.

Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dnslookupdotnet.aspx?fid=228105&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2262247) for one.  Others are easy to find with Google/Bing.

Comment: Just tested the open-source project in the link and it worked great for pulling A Records and Nameservers. Open the DnsExample project and change the Query() method return the Response instead of printing it out. Change project type to Library, recompile, then you got yourself a library that can do DNS lookups. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SimpleDNS](https://www.kitson-online.co.uk/simpledns-a-simple-but-comprehensive-dns-library-for-c/) which provides results for Query Types **A**, **CName**, **MX**, **NS**, **SOA** and **TXT**.

```
//Create your question - (Hostname,QueryType) 
var question = new Question("stackoverflow.com", QType.NS);

//Create your SimpleDnsPacket and pass to the Util method Kitson.Dns.Query 
var result = Query.Simple(new SimpleDnsPacket(question, IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8")));
```

**Result:**

[image]

It's also available as [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleDNS/1.0.0) package and compatible with .NetCore 2.0.