# Dns.GetHostEntry strange behavior

Tags: c#, .net, dns

I need to know the ip address assigned to the machine in which my program is running.
To achieve this, .NET Framework has the `System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(string)` method.
On my machine I can call GetHostEntry passing the loopback address (127.0.0.1) and the network adapter address (10.5.8.160) and I get the same the same result.
What I noticed is that on another pc if I call GetHostEntry passing the loopback address it returns just one address: 127.0.0.1. If the method is called passing the network adapter address (192.9.210.83) it returns several addresses, including the loopback (127.0.0.1 and ::1).
The difference i could see is that my pc has only one ethernet connection, the other pc has two ethernet connections and a wireless one.
What is the reason behind this difference?

Comment: "the IP address assigned to the machine" - this is not well defined. There can be any number of IP addresses (including 0) assigned to your machine.

Comment: @KlausGütter this is exactly what I mean. Let's the the machine has 3 ips: 192.10.8.15, 10.5.8.160, 192.0.0.74. If I call `Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1")` what I get is only 127.0.0.1.
If `Dns.GetHostEntry("10.5.8.160")` is called instead I get all 3 addresses listed above.

What I'm tryong to undestand is why there is this difference.

Comment: Dns.GetHostEntry queries the DNS server for information about the host. Obviously, for 127.0.0.1, there is no DNS server to ask, so the method just returns some local information.

Comment: It makes sense. But, in my pc calling `Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1")` and `Dns.GetHostEntry("10.5.8.159")` gives the same addresses: 127.0.0.1 and 10.5.8.159.

Comment: Maybe some entry in the hosts file? Useful information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910622/what-does-dns-gethostentry-methodstring-actually-do